# Debug multiple projects with a time lapse before their respective startups

Tags: c#, visual-studio-debugging, multiple-projects

Preface: I've looked over other posts about multi-project debugging, and I've found recommendations to configure multiple startup projects. Unfortunately, this doesn't fit the bill for my scenario.

I'm working on a C# project (VS 2005, Win7 32-bit) made up of 3 solutions, each containing around 40 projects. I want to debug the ENTIRE application at run-time, but here's the problem: after the first/main solution is started, 5 to 10 seconds must elapse before starting 2nd solution, followed by another lapse before the 3rd solution is started. These time lapses are necessitated by run-time initializations that must complete in each solution before the next can be started. Clear as mud?

Does anyone know how I can accomplish the above AND allow the lapses to occur?
I can't manually "Attach to Process" because I'm trying to debug each solution's 1st and 2nd class as they're instantiated. I was hoping VS 2005 had an option to run a particular DLL in debug mode when an EXE starts, but if such a feature exists I can't find it. I recall being able to do this many moons ago in VS 6.0. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think we need more information on the relationship between the projects and why the lapses are needed.

Comment: And as an alternative, I imagine that any such startup sequencing would be beneficial in production as well.  For NT Services, look at dependencies.  For Web Services and other hosted services, some other techniques could be used.  If these are applications running on a single box, named events could be used.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and suggestions.
Millie, the reason for 3 solutions is too convoluted to explain here. Even though this is not an installation application, that makes a good analogy: a script installs the base; upon completion it invokes a script that's dependent on the contents of the base, etc...
Mitch, the entire program is a client. No web services or server-side calls involved. I'll have a look at named events and see where that leads me. One approach I haven't spent enough time on is the one described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed(v=vs.80).aspx